# Accessing virtualbox shared folder from an SSH cygwin session

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, virtualbox, cygwin

I'm using the Shared Folder feature of Virtual box.

When I double click on the Share in My Computer it gets mounted to letter E and I can then access it from a GUI terminal Window inside the guest under `/cygdrive/E`.

However, when I log in remotely the mount is no longer visible and `/cygdrive` only lists drive `C`.

How can I access the shared folder from inside an SSH session? Better yet, can this be done completely without any GUI interaction at all (no double clicking on the share in the guest's GUI)?

I have found this thread on the Cygwin mailing list, which looks most relate to my problem, however, no resolution: https://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg165716.html .

Comment: you need it to be mounted for the user before connecting from Cygwin SSH.

Comment: @matzeri I've tried that, of course. The problem is, the mount doesn't appear visible to ssh connections, even if those connections come after the mount.

Comment: Have you any cygwin process running before the mount ?